# Como testar o horário de verão em PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

Tem um app desenvolvido em PHP o qual retorna o horário da entrega de uma encomenda. Porém como estamos no horário de verão a data esta vindo errada. 
Como posso corrigir isso no php ?

Comment: Qual servidor você está usando? Talvez o ideal seria que o servidor atualizasse a data automaticamente.

Comment: Porque ao invés de usar horário local não usa o storage (gravar no banco) como UTC/GMT e então somente no momento de exibir ajusta o horário local setando a "timezone"? Pois eu presumo que seu problema é que esta gravando de uma maneira que vai conflitar depois.